# Symfony related manytomany object query

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to query related objects and I have some problems.. Hopefully someone of you can help me out.

So, I have two `ManyToMany` related entity

**User entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Contact", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_contacts")
 */
protected $contacts;
```

and **Contact entity**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="contacts")
*/
protected $users;
```

**Table: Users_contacts** is following

```
User_id **** Contact_id

1 ------------ 1
2 ------------ 1
3 ------------ 2
4 ------------ 2
```

I'm trying to get `user_ids` related to queried `contact_id`

I have already tried multiple different querybuilder

for example:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
->innerJoin('u.contacts', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.id = :$user_id')
->setParameter('user_id', $user_id);
```

but without result and currently I have

```
$test = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findAll();
```

**twig**

```
{% for user in test %}
   {{ users.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

which gets me contact_id, but how I get user_ids related to it? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the related many to many entity by doing `$user->getContact()` or inside twig template `{{ user.contact }}`. Instead of writting the getter all alone you can follow the next steps:

1. You should have 2 main tables and a pivot table: user, contact and user_has_contact
2. user_has_contact should content two rows: user_id and contact_id
3. Create the FKs in both tables

[image: Simple table]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`contact` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user_has_contact` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `contact_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `contact_id`),
  INDEX `fk_user_has_contact_contact1_idx` (`contact_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_user_has_contact_user_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_has_contact_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_has_contact_contact1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`contact` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

4. Map the tables and generate the entities. You can do this using reverse engineering. [See documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)
5. You should now have inside User.php the getter (also the setter) for retrieving the associated contacts.